# How to upload an image to Wasabi using Golang?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, wasabi

I'm trying to figure out how to upload an image/ file to a Wasabi Bucket using Golang. Amazon updated the S3 Golang client library to [version 2](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/) and I'm having a hard time piecing everything together how exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after a few hours of brutal trial and error, I finally figured it out. Hopefully this saves someone hours of work in the future!

```
const (
    ACCESS_KEY = "access-key"
    SECRET_KEY = "secret-key"

    REGION = "ap-southeast-2"
    ENDPOINT := "https://s3.ap-southeast-2.wasabisys.com"
)

func UploadImagesToWasabi() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx,
        config.WithRegion(REGION),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, "")),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(
            func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
                return aws.Endpoint{
                    URL: ENDPOINT,
                }, nil
            },
        )),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create an Amazon S3 service client
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    bucketName := "bucket-name"
    objectKey := "preferrably-filename"
    filePath := "path/to/file"

    // Get the file
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to read file:", err)
        return
    }

    // Upload the file to the Wasabi bucket
    result, err := client.PutObject(ctx, &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
        Body:   file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to upload file:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Successfully uploaded file: %v/n", result)
}
```

Make sure to set the correct endpoint for your bucket region otherwise you'll get this error: `api error InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

[List of Wasabi Region Endpoints/ Service Urls](https://docs.wasabi.com/docs/what-are-the-service-urls-for-wasabis-different-storage-regions)

Feel free to suggest a cleaner/ more optimized way of writing this!